# UITapGestureRecognizer interefering with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller that attaches a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to its main `UIView`, and enables the user to tap the screen to make the status, navigation, and tool bars reappear / disappear (like the photos app). I also have a `UIScrollView` attached to the main `UIView` which implements zooming and thus has its own `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to implement scrolling and zooming.

The problem I'm having, is when going to zoom / scroll the `UIScrollView`, it's very sensitive to picking up the `UITapGestureRecognizer` which is attached to the main `UIView`. It seems a lot of the time the `UITapGestureRecognizer` gets triggered when it shouldn't. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this for versions of ios below 5.0? Is there someway I can override the simultaneous gestures delegate method for the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in the `UIScrollView` and prevent the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from firing during other gestures?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method.

```
[tapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:pinchGestureRecognizer];
```

This call tells the tap recognizer to wait for the pinch recognizer to fail.

Comment: Thanks. Couple questions 1) Is it possible to obtain the UIScrollView pinchgesturerecognizer before ios5? 2) Where do I need to make this call and how many times? Is it possible I can also require it to fail for UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I'm away from my computer, and will be for awhile. All UIViews have an array property `gestureRecognizers` that you can access their recognizers with. The require to fail only needs to be called once. I check for more specifics when I get a chance.

Comment: I had expected this to work and had tried it in my own app. Unfortunately didn't solve the issue for me.